# jsonapi_resource GET call not returning data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails. I have been trying to so a follow along project. Basically trying out CRUD API.

My routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  get '/', to: 'status#index'
  jsonapi_resource :authors
end
```

ApplicationController.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include JSONAPI::ActsAsResourceController
end
```

AuthorResource

```
class AuthorResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  attributes :first, :last
end
```

Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2023_02_02_083747) do

  create_table "authors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first"
    t.string "last"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

end
```

When I try to add authors via POST call, data is getting added to DB. But GET call returns a error response

POST CALL REQ/RES

```
{
    "data":{
        "type":"authors",
        "attributes":{
            "first":"Yuval",
            "last":"Harari"

        }
    }
}



{
    "data": {
        "id": "4",
        "type": "authors",
        "links": {
            "self": "http://localhost:3000/authors/4"
        },
        "attributes": {
            "first": "Yuval",
            "last": "Harari"
        }
    }
}

Response for GET call

{
    "errors": [
        {
            "title": "Record not found",
            "detail": "The record identified by  could not be found.",
            "code": "404",
            "status": "404"
        }
    ]
}
```

ERROR IN CONSOLE

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/authors/4"):
```

Can anybody help me understand the problem please ? I am using rails v 6.1.7

Comment: Instead of using curl/postman write [an integration test](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing) that can be reproduced (by us) and which will help you safeguard against future regressions. Here we have no idea what steps you may have done (or not done) and its near impossible to actually help you.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment max. I am still in the learning process, once I complete the testing part will come back. Also I forgot to mention the error that i got in the console. This is the error `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/authors/4"):`

Comment: That means you're most likely using the wrong URI. Run `rails routes -c authors` in your shell to get a list of routes.

Comment: Also if your new to rails you probally shouldn't be using a gem like `jsonapi_resource` as it hides away so much of what you should be learning with magic.

Comment: I tried asking same question with ChatGPT, it asked me to write a method show in author controller and render in json format. It worked !!! :) But my doubt is the follow along tutorial which i referred, did not write any such controller function, it worked as it is for him. But not for me, that is what I am wondering

Comment: Again - what you're doing isn't a very good way to learn Rails. Start with the basics and actually learn to use the conventions, framework and tools before you use a gem that  abstracts away 90% of the job and which will be impossible for you to comprehend or debug.

Comment: Thanks a lot mike ! Will surely work on that

Comment: I want to reiterate sticking with just Rails at first. Especially with regard to this gem, I've used [jsonapi-resources](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources) before and it's garbage. If I interviewed somewhere and was told the company used it I'd walk out, that's how bad it is.